# Uploading data in Firestore Database using Kotlin. Unable to store data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

**I don't know what is the problem but the String from the Edittext is not getting stored in my Firestore Database.Please help i am new to Firestore and kotlin as well**

> MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val mFirestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameText)//nameText.text.toString()
    val user = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userText)
    val occ = "Student"

    val usermap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    usermap.put("Name", name.text.toString())
    usermap.put("Occupation", occ)
    usermap.put("Type", user.text.toString())

    button.setOnClickListener() {

        mFirestore.collection("Users").add(usermap).addOnSuccessListener() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
}
```

**This my firestore database screenshot please check it and help me**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op1Y2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the values in your `EditText`s immediately (and only once) when they're created - they're still empty at this point. Instead, read their value in the callback of the listener every time, like so:

```
button.setOnClickListener() {
    val usermap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    usermap.put("Name", name.text.toString())
    usermap.put("Occupation", occ)
    usermap.put("Type", user.text.toString())

    mFirestore.collection("Users").add(usermap).addOnSuccessListener() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```